# Python opening a txt file converted from pdf

Tags: python-3.x

I downloaded from http://icdept.cgaux.org/pdf_files/English-Italian-Glossary-Nautical-Terms.pdf the pdf file and converted it to a txt file using pdf2txt ( downloaded from iTunes) I am trying to convert the contents of the file to a searchable Python dictionary(I am studying for an Italian sailing licence).
I am using simply to test whether I can get the text into a format that I can parse :

```
with open('English-Italian-Glossary-Nautical-Terms1.txt', 'r') as out_file:
    with open("nautical_glossary.txt", 'w') as in_file:
        for line in out_file:
            in_file.write(line)
```

but constantly get an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/untitled folder/nautical.py", line 4, in <module>
    for line in out_file:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would appreciate some help understanding the error and a suggestion to resolve the problem.
I am not sure whether someone can suggest an obvious way to parse this particular file into a dictionary format?

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that the coding of the file is not the expected. See on [wikipedia about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Code_unit). In other words, he doesn't know what does `0xfe` mean.

You should find the correct encoding of the file and open with it. I suspect it is utf-8, but I could be wrong. Did you tried to open the file to see how it is?

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html?highlight=readlines#codecs.StreamReader.readlines) and try this:

```
with open('English-Italian-Glossary-Nautical-Terms1.txt', 'r') as out_file:
    with open("nautical_glossary.txt", 'w') as in_file:
        for line in out_file.readlines():
            in_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks to both of you for trying to help. Still gives the decoding problem I'm afraid

Comment: Curious! I read the information in:http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html and encoding = "latin-1" and now have a legible file. Now I shall have to see whether the nautical_glossary can be parsed to give a key,value dictionary file

Comment: Could you please post your actual code and what do you want to achieve? It would be easier that way

Comment: Did you specify the coding of the python script ? `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-`. "utf-8" for example (instead of default ascii)

Comment: I have specified the encoding as "latin-1" which allows the file to be read and writes to another file. However when I try for line in filename.redlines(): print line I get ( first entry only) abaftï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿verso poppaï»¿ of which abaft and verso poppa are the only sensible characters.

Comment: The coding line in your python script must be the same as the coding used for the script itself, not for the file to be read. For the file, you can try [bytes().decode()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)